# MySQL: Update SET and WHERE both determined by one subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't have any idea how to do this..

I have a table like this:

```
account_categories
--------------------
id  | description
--------------------
34  | Home Services
35  | Home Services
36  | Home Services
39  | Home Design
40  | Home Design
```

I have another table (accounts) that references account_categories.id and it uses all of the above values.  :/

I want to flatten account_categories, so I need to pick one duplicate from account_categories and update accounts so that all duplicates use the one selected value.

For instance, I need to turn this:

```
accounts
---------------------
id  | accountCategory
---------------------
1   | 34
2   | 35
3   | 36
4   | 39
5   | 40
```

Into this:

```
accounts
---------------------
id  | accountCategory
---------------------
1   | 34
2   | 34
3   | 34
4   | 39
5   | 39
```

I can select an id and distinct description from account categories like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (description), id
FROM crmalpha.account_categories
GROUP BY description
```

But I guess that the next step is to do something like this:

```
for ( row in ( SELECT DISTINCT (description), id FROM crmalpha.account_categories GROUP BY description ) ) {
    UPDATE crmalpha.accounts SET accountCategory = $row['id'] WHERE accountCategory IN ( SELECT id FROM crmalpha.account_categories WHERE description = $row['description] )
}
```

Forgive the for loop and php variable pseudo code, I'm just trying to think through it logically.  I have no idea how to accomplish this in pure SQL.

Any ideas?

PS., Afterwards, I will go through and delete from account_categories every row where the ID is not used in the accounts table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked when I tried it against the test data you posted above. That said, when doing any mass cleanup like this I'd recommend making a copy of the table first. Also check results after issuing the `UPDATE` and before issuing a `COMMIT`.

Here's the query:

```
UPDATE Accounts acct
INNER JOIN Account_Categories cat ON acct.AccountCategory = cat.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(id) AS NewID, Description
  FROM Account_Categories
  GROUP BY Description) NewCat ON cat.Description = NewCat.Description
SET acct.AccountCategory = NewCat.NewID
```

Some explanation:

- The subquery (`SELECT MIN(id)...`) gets a single ID value (the lowest one) for each description.
- The first join (to `Account_Categories`) associates each account with its category for the sole purpose of having the decription available.
- The second join (to the subquery) associates the account's existing description to the table of flattened/de-duped descriptions and their ID.

Comment: I confirmed that worked.  Thanks Ed, that's pretty amazing.  I'm going to have to take a second read over this SQL to try and really grok it.  .... Got it, thanks again!

Comment: That's great news; I'm glad it worked for you! If you have any followup questions just ask away and I'll do my best to answer.